# Tinybutstrong opentbs ote=changepic adjust parameter cannot be used in block section, it causes template crash

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

The parameter adjust for [x.x;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;adjust] paramater is not working in a block section.

I want to loop through a set of results and add an image for each result given. This is working without the adjust parameter, but this looks very ugly since the images are, as expected, not adjusted with height and width.

How can I make this work in a template so I have an adjusted image for each result in a block section?

Adding and removing the adjust parameter. Adjust outside the block parameter is working, but then I only have 1 result and cannot loop through my set of results.

Version: OpenTBS 1.10.7

Comment: `adjust` in a section works fine for the DOCX example in the packaged provided with OpenTBS.
What is your type of document ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the code I have 

[opportunities.opportunity_id;block=begin]

This is my image tag inside the image: [opportunities.test_image;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;adjust]

[opportunities.opportunity_id;block=end]

When I remove 'adjust', it works as expected, but then my image is not sized that pretty. When I add the parameter 'adjust' it doesn't work and the XML in the docx is corrupt. When you don't have a section with a block then it does work but then I cannot loop through my set of results.